How to get start with spring framework project, and how to get start to understand the flow
I am new to spring framework project, I recently cloned this project and also setup it in my local. But I am not getting ideat to start it. Could you please help me, in how can I start to understant this project.
I have cloned the repo, I go though the reference documentation and also the guild.

"Could you please help me, in how can I start to understant this project." - it's a GIGANTIC project...there's no secret to learning it...it's step by step, day by day. In the words of Nike, "Just Do It". Start reading, try the quick start guides, do small projects, etc...

Without access to the repo, that's impossible for anyone here to answer.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
